# How do I push to a 2-attribute per element array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I want to achieve the following array structure but programmatically by using the push() function in js:

```
var arr = [
{id: 1, txt: "First Element"},
{id: 2, txt: "Second Element"},
{id: 3, txt: "Third Element"}
];
```

My idea is something of the following format:

```
var arr = [];
var id = 1;
var text = "First Element";

for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
arr.push({id,text});
}
```

This is wrong because I'm not passing the column names anywhere. How do I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: `int`? does it work? where do you get the columns from?

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry that was a mistake because I'm writing Java at the same time and typed this real quick :((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there, you just need to specify both the property name and the value, like this:

```js
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr.push({ id : i+1, txt : "Element " + (i+1) });
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the swift reply!